# Safari changes ARIA HTML features?

Tags: html, ios, safari, wai-aria, changelog

I have a web-app that is also compiled and sold on iOS App store using PhoneGap.
My App handy tool for the Blind and those who work with Braille & requires ARIA to pass the UI info to VoiceOver.

I use to use `aria-labelledby` as a critical component, to do this in my HTML tags.

On iOS 4.3.5 it worked fine all the way I think up through 5.0 ...
But some where along the way it broke. Because in iOS 6.1.4 it doesn't want to work (iPhone5) or on 6.1.3 (iPad2).
However `aria-describedby` does now work; while previously it didn't..

Is there a break down some where with a changelog of how these ARIA features have been changed over time. I've searched the Apple Dev site to no avail.

Thanks a bunch.
-David

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.marcozehe.de/2013/03/08/sometimes-you-have-to-use-illegal-wai-aria-to-make-stuff-work/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the safari media queries for the same